# After a successful question spree, let's now clean up the unanswered queue!

Tags: discussion, participation, site-stats, unanswered-questions

The campaign to reach 10 questions/day:

- [ATTENTION Matter Modelers: Can we ask 30 questions in the next 24 hours?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/174/5)
- [Matter Modeling needs a lot more questions before 28 July: Here's why](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/5)
- [Salvaging the DFT questions and questions that fall unambiguously within our territory, from other sites](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/171/5)

Was a SUCCESS!

[image]

But with this success, we have also lost some of the [success we had achieved just before](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/61-of-our-questions-have-been-answered-should-we-focus-on-improving-this#comment244_66) in our campaign to make our percentage of questions answered higher.

To climb back up to 90% while our questions/day metric is high, we just need 21 unanswered questions answered, and I think the following are very do-able!

1. [I get an error 'Conversion from Z-matrix to cartesian coordinates failed' in Gaussian09. Any suggestions?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1765/5) (get this user's G09 input running without the error) ***DONE by Tyberius***
2. [What resources are available to learn how to do something in VASP?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1830/5) (add VASPwiki and others) ***DONE by ProfM***
3. [Calculate free energy for a canonical (NVT) ensemble](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1673/5) (the comment chain indicates that the question can be *temporarily* closed until more details are added, since our top user of the MD tag says the question is too unclear for them to answer. *The user has given us permission to close the question*) ***DONE by Tyberius***
4. **[Is the non-trivial band topology in a system, caused by spin-orbit-coupling or band inversion?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1800/5) (ProfM seems already to have answered some of it in a different question linked in the comments?)**
5. [Citizen science projects in Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1786/5) (I can answer it) ***DONE***
6. [What are the types of DMRG?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1781/5) (I'll **learn** enough to answer it if I **have to**, but I'm volunteering to answer a lot more of these, so it will be hard time-wise. I would appreciate help here since I'm not a DMRG expert). ***DONE***
7. [How to automatically plot atomic structures with magnetic moments?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1780/5) (Cody's comment suggest he might be able to answer it?) ***DONE***
8. [Parallel algorithms on unstructured closed graphs](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1777/5) (could potentially be migrated to one of the SEs listed in the comments, but not absolutely necessary yet).
9. [What's the largest system we can study based on "fundamental limits to computation"?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1755/5) (I can try to answer it if we're **really deparate** but would have to read the paper first. Hopefully we can answer enough other questions quickly).
10. [Interpreting electron localization function (ELF) results](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1721/5) (Cody described the ELF in the partial charges question, perhaps he can answer?)
11. [Structural biology vs condensed matter prediction](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1719/5) (I can try to answer if necessary)
12. [Orbital-free DFT and Density Functional Tight-Binding: Comparison](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1696/5) (vcw says in the comments that they might at least know the OF-DFT part, just not the DFTB part).
13. [What packages exist for building quantum Monte Carlo simulations of spin Hamiltonians?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1695/5) (I'll answer)
14. [What are the ways to add dynamic correlation to an MCSCF wavefunction?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1685/5) (I can try to **learn** enough to answer, but it will take time)
15. [What are real examples where fractals were used in Matter Modeling?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1679/5) (The reference that Anyon gave the comments makes it easy for someone to answer. Anyon said they may not be able to).
16. [Why are single excitations ignored in the MP2 component of double hybrids functional calculations?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1665/5) (Tyberius said he might be able to answer)
17. [How do the various programs read or write integrals in FCIDUMP format?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1643/5) (I might be able to answer, but will be short on time)
18. [Can we "invert" Density Functional Theory through sufficiently accurate experiment?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1642/5) (Cody and Camps seem to have answers, based on the comments?)
19. [What are the types of Quantum Molecular Dynamics (QMD)?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1630/5) (I'll try to answer if absolutely necessary if I have time, Tyberius said he could also)
20. [Examples of matter modeling in fiction](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1608/5) (I'll try to answer if absolutely necessary, but time will be getting very short).

The following don't seem too much harder than the above:

- [How to extract lattice constants a and c from relaxed hexagonal structure using VASP?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1808/5)
- [Coupling between 1st and 2nd order phase transitions?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1813/5)
- [Properties that can be deduced from Band structure and DOS](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1791/5)
- [How can I draw the energy bands for the first and second zones of Brillouin? Is it conductor or insulator?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1772/5)
- [DFT code for quantum simulation of atomic heat transport](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1760/5)
- [Theories for electronic transport calculations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1749/5)
- [Which software programs can be used to study SRR (split ring resonator) based meta-material and its cloaking properties](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1747/5)
- [Charge density wave and band inversion](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1743/5)
- [How does infinite DMRG work?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1739/5)
- [For which materials is the Bethe lattice a good model to compute the density of states of the conduction band?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1734/5)
- [Which DMRG package has the easiest learning curve?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1732/5)
- [Anomalous Quantum Hall Effect](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1768/5)
- [What are the top journals that focus on or cover matter modeling?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1694/5)
- [Overcoherence problem in Ehrenfest dynamics](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1676/5)
- [What is the difference between Ehrenfest dynamics and Born-Oppenheimer Molecular Dynamics?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1675/5)
- [Sample LAMMPS file for graphene growth on a metal surface](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1624/5)
- [Calculations using SIESTA and TranSIESTA](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1610/5)